# Proof by induction for recursive function

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I have watched several proof by induction tutorials, and I kinda get them for the simple cases, but for one of my tutorials, I have no idea how to apply it here.

Disclaimer: I am allowed to discuss this with friends, but I do not know anyone so I am seeking help here. I've tried doing something, and need some clarifications.

Here is the question:

Suppose the function f is defined recursively as follows: $f (1) = 0$ and $$f (n) = 2f \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \lg(n)$$ for $n$ that is a power of $2$. Prove by induction that $f(n) = 2n − \lg(n) − 2$.

What I did:

I used the first $f(1)$ and $f(n)$ to try to prove the base case, which I have chosen $n$ as $2$.

And when I got $f(2)$, I then did the RHS with the second $f(n)$ that was provided aka $f(n) = 2n − \lg(n) − 2$.

I can confirm that the recursive function (LHS) and the other non-recursive function (RHS) matches.

I then go on to assume $n = k$ is true, and then try to prove for $n = 2k$ but I am not sure how to proceed for here, as I don't see any pattern or anything.

Here is my working: I am not sure how to prove that my $f(2k)$ is true

---

Base case: $n=2$:

LHS:

$$\begin{align}
f(2)&=2f\left(\frac22\right) + \lg(2)\\
&=2f(1)+\lg(2)\\
&=2(0)+\lg(2)\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

RHS:

$$\begin{align}
f(2)&=2n-\lg(2)-2\\
&=2(2)-\lg(2) - 2\\
&=2-\lg(2)\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

so LHS=RHS.

Inductive step:

Assume $n=k$ is true. $$f(k)=2k-\lg(k)-2$$ (is this correct?)

Now, prove that $n=2k$ is true.

\begin{align}
f(2)&=2(2k) - \lg(2k)-2\\
&=???
\end{align}

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

Your base case is okay.
For your inductive step, you have to assume that

$f(k) = 2k-lg(k)-2$ is true and use the property that $lg(2k) = lg(k) +1 $.

Then we can verify that:

$$f(2k) = 2f(k)+lg(2k)$$

$$=2(2k-lg(k)-2)+lg(2k)$$

$$=4k-2lg(k)-4+lg(2k)$$

$$=4k-2lg(k)-4+lg(k)+1$$

$$=4k-2lg(k)+lg(k)-3$$

$$=4k-lg(k)-3$$

$$=4k-lg(2k)+1-3$$

$$=4k-lg(2k)-2$$

which completes the inductive step.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I previously tried reworking my induction step: https://i.imgur.com/wRV7Jpc.png a few questions 1) For your inductive step, '4−2()−4+()+1' may I know how you broke up the lg(2n) into lg(n) + 1? 2) Is it normal to use 'n' again? As I realised most people change it to 'k' during induction

Comment: @Stan yes, you almost got it. The only thing that you need to use is the breaking up of lg(2n) into lg(n)+1. Because it is logarithm with base 2, you have the sequence $2^0, 2^1, ...$ so the power increases with $1$ all the time and that's why lg(2n) can be written as $lg(n)+1$. I edited my answer with 'k' instead of 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

$f(k)=2k - \lg(k) - 2$ is OK, yes.

Now, you need to assume that the above equation is **true**, and prove that if it is true, then, if $l=2k$, the equation $$f(l) = 2l - \lg(l) - 2$$  is also true.

This means that you need to **prove** that $f(2k)=2k - \lg(2k)-2$. When you ask how do I proceed, that doesn't make any sense. What you wrote is not your start, it is your finish line.

What you start with is the two things you already know are true about the function:

1. $f(k)=2k-\lg k - 2$
2. $f(n) = 2f(\frac{n}{2})+\lg n$

I suggest your next step is to subsitute $n=2k$ in the second equation, and go from there.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for editing my question and providing such helpful feedback. What you said make sense, and I see what you mean now. I tried working based on your suggestions and I just wanted to check if I am on the right track: https://i.imgur.com/wRV7Jpc.png Am I supposed to turn 4k - 2 lg(k) - 4 + lg(2k) into 2(2k)-lg(2k)-2?

Comment: @Stan $$4k-2\lg k - 4 +\lg(2k) = 2(2k) - 2 - 2 - \lg(k^2) + \lg(2k)$$

now, change one of the twos into $\lg 4$ and try to merge all of the logarithms using the rule $\lg(ab)=\lg a + \lg b$ and the like

Comment: @Stan Did my additional hint help you or are you still stuck?